# Provide update only for iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, compatibility, updates, ios7

We have decided to drop support for ios < 7 with the next update of our app (its a small project so there is no big issue here).

my question is - will ios6,5,... users still be able to use the last version of the app, or will they be provided with the same update as ios 7 users and have a non-working app from there on?

in extension: how do we create a build that will only be available for ios7 users and not mess with older versions of the app for non-update users? is it sufficient to specivy `Deployment target: ios 7` in xcode?

Comment: I've read an article saying that Apple introduced legacy app support in their Store. source: http://mashable.com/2013/09/17/ios-legacy-apps/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since last week, Apple gives people on older iOS versions the option to download the latest compatible version of an app.

Updating an app to a a version that's no longer supported was always restricted, and it is sufficient to set the Deployment Target in the General settings to the desired minimum iOS version.